# Android code to handle apps closed by swiping away

Tags: android, sqlite, swipe

Is there anyone knowing how I can handle the code when apps closed by swiping away? I just want to update my sqlite database when the apps closed by swiping away, so it can't work using `onPause()` or `onStop()`, and so on with `onDestroy()`, because it can't handle the force closed by swiping away.. Any solutions? Thank you very much..

Comment: isnt onDestroy() being called when you close the app?

Comment: @Nanoc onDestroy() just being called when you press back button from one activity to another.. but it's not being called when I close the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no listener that trigger when "swiping away", You can handle the onStop in all activities to know when the user stop.

Maybe you need to change the way your app works, and update the sqlite database in others cirscuantances that fills better with your app

if you still want to follow that way, there is a tricky solution,

You can start a service that ask the app "if it is running or not" every 'X' time, but that will drain the battery and is a DONT DO IT ( from my perspective)

Comment: oh i see, so there's no listener for that case.. Anyway, thank you for answering.. I will think another way then..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't, and there isn't such an event.

That said, if you have data you need to save, do it while you can, e.g. onPause/onStop. Assume the user left your app. If he later resumes it, you can undo what you've updated, if necessary.